# What was the name of the 'visitor' race?

Tags: v-2009

Throughout V (2009 remake) the 'Visitors' are referred to as 'Vs' and 'Visitors' - is the actual name of the visiting race ever mentioned at any point during the TV series?

What was the name of the 'visitor' race?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no name given to them rather than [Visitors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitors_%28V%29), even in both the series. The "Visitors" are reptilian humanoids who disguise themselves to look human but prefer to eat live prey. All Visitors are given human names for the humans' convenience. They are never heard to use their home-world names.

For more details click [here](http://v.wikia.com/wiki/The_Visitors).

Comment: Their name is stated as unknown in this reference. http://v.wikia.com/wiki/The_Visitors

Comment: No, I was agreeing with your answer. Just providing another reference. The question was what was their species called, not what did they call each other.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini ohh... sorry for misunderstanding